# How to scroll the scroller vertically when the user selects a div and goes up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple divs in a page.
Two buttons "UP" and "Down".User can select a div and can move the selected div up using "UP" button or down using "Down" button.

I want to move the vertical scroll move upward and downward as user moves the selected div up or down respectively.

How this can be achieved using javascript or jquery?

Comment: show us what have you tried?

Comment: or you know... search. This has been covered thousands of times.

Comment: you may use http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myId");
var position = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
var y_pos = position.top;

var moveByDistance = 10;  //specify by how many pixel the div should move

function moveup() {
  y_pos = y_pos - moveByDistance;
  myDiv.style.marginTop = y_pos + "px";
}
function movedown() {
  y_pos = y_pos + moveByDistance;
  myDiv.style.marginTop = y_pos + "px";
}
```

```html
<div id="myId">Div content
  <button id="up" onclick="moveup()">Up</button>
  <button id="down" onclick="movedown()">Down</button>
</div>
```